# Find all possible set of two combinations in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations

Given an array of size n which will be even always, I need to output all possible combinations of 2 pair elements.

I have this:

```
let teams = ["team1","team2","team3","team4"]
```

what I tried:

```
function pairs(arr) {
    var res = [],
        l = arr.length;
    for(var i=0; i<l; ++i)
        for(var j=i+1; j<l; ++j)
            res.push([arr[i], arr[j]]);
    return res;
}

pairs(teams).forEach(function(pair){
    console.log(pair);
});

//outputs

[ 'team1', 'team2' ]
[ 'team1', 'team3' ]
[ 'team1', 'team4' ]
[ 'team2', 'team3' ]
[ 'team2', 'team4' ]
[ 'team3', 'team4' ]
```

This seems fine but some are missing for example I don't see the following :

```
[ 'team2', 'team1' ] 
[ 'team3', 'team1' ]
[ 'team3', 'team2' ]
[ 'team4', 'team1' ]
[ 'team4', 'team2' ]
[ 'team4', 'team3' ]
```

So my expected output is the above and previous result in the code I posted above.

Notice that I don't need them in particular order as long as I get all the possible combinations.

Comment: so you are getting `[ 'team1', 'team2' ]` but want to get both `[ 'team1', 'team2' ]` and `[ 'team2', 'team1' ]`? if yes, then why do you say "you don't need them in particular order"?

Comment: Can't you just take your current output and add in arrays that are the `.reverse()` of your arrays?

Comment: @skyboyer I think it is clear to say I meant that by the output. and it is tournament schedule so each team should play home/away.

Comment: When order does not matter, it's a combination. When order does matter, it's a permutation.

Comment: yeah but I don't need in them any order by that I mean the output in pairs.

Comment: @user7716943 then just double(process twice) array you already have.

Comment: @skyboyer nah I don't think that is good idea.

Comment: Just to be clear, order does matter here - *order* refers to the ordering of the two teams in a single match where `['team1', 'team2']` is considered different to `['team2', 'team1']` (because they are home and away matches). Order does not relate to the sequence of matches in the results list. And because order matters, this is a permutation, not a combination.

Comment: why? with that your code uses 2x less memory and needs N less operations than two full loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functional JS:

```js
let teams = ["team1", "team2", "team3", "team4"];

var result = teams.flatMap( (v) => 
  teams.
    filter( w => v!=w ).
    map   ( w => [v, w] ) 
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Note, if using Node.js, that this requires 11.0.0 or later.

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to do more combinatorics than this simple example, then you can use the [js-combinatorics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-combinatorics) package. For example:

```
const Combinatorics = require('js-combinatorics');

const teams = ['team1', 'team2', 'team3', 'team4'];

const matches = Combinatorics.permutation(teams, 2).toArray();

console.log(matches);
```

Output is:

```
[
  [ 'team1', 'team2' ],
  [ 'team2', 'team1' ],
  [ 'team1', 'team3' ],
  [ 'team3', 'team1' ],
  [ 'team2', 'team3' ],
  [ 'team3', 'team2' ],
  [ 'team1', 'team4' ],
  [ 'team4', 'team1' ],
  [ 'team2', 'team4' ],
  [ 'team4', 'team2' ],
  [ 'team3', 'team4' ],
  [ 'team4', 'team3' ]
]
```

Comment: I think this is a good option, I will try it out as I will need more complex combinatorics later.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the possible combinations including reverse duplicates, you need to iterate j loop from 0 to array's length as well.

```js
for(let i = 0; i < l; i++) 
  for(let j = 0; j < l; j++) {
    if(i == j) continue; // skip the same index
    res.push([arr[i], arr[j]]); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i<l; ++i)
    {
        for(var j=0; j<l; ++j)
        {
            if(i!=j)
            res.push([arr[i], arr[j]]);
        }
    }
```

Above code will generate all pairs

Answer (score 0):

```
array.flatMap(x => array.map(y => x !== y ? x + ' ' + y : null)).filter(x => x)
```